# R character string sourcing

Tags: regex, r

Hopefully this shouldn't be too complicated....but I have the following character string in `x`, and would like it to to be programmatically sourced as a function such that I can type in

```
HW.R()
```

to generate 100 random normals....i.e. what operations do I need to perform on `x` for that to happen?

below is the code to generate `x`

```
require(RCurl)
x <- base64Decode("SFcuUiA8LSBmdW5jdGlvbigpewogIHJub3JtKDEwMCkKfQ==\n")
x
[1] "HW.R <- function(){\n  rnorm(100)\n}"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you suspected, it's not at all complicated. This should get the job done:

```
x <- "HW.R <- function(){\n  rnorm(100)\n}"
eval(parse(text = x))

HW.R
# function(){
#   rnorm(100)
# }
```

Alternatively, you can use `source()`, as long as you first "wrap" `x` in a `textConnection`:

```
source(file = textConnection(x))
length(HW.R())
# [1] 100
```

Comment: I wish I could give you an additional upvote for the textConnection edit as well.